# Is there a way to get the antilog in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I've been given a data set and have inputted the values into R. For the assignment question you need to replicate the following equation: y= 0.08x^0.75.

In order to turn this into an equation that fits into y = Bo + B1x, I took the log10 of both sides using the following code.

```
fit <- lm(log10(Predator_Biomass)~log10(Prey_Biomass))
summary(fit)
```

From this I was able to obtain: y = -1.1050 + 0.7450x

Now I've been instructed that I need to take the antilog of both sides so that the Bo value will match 0.08 or be somewhat similar. Is there an antilog function in R that could be helpful to this? Any information would be helpful.

EDIT: Apparently everything that was offered as an answer only took a antilog of the coefficients and not the entire equation. Is there a way to take the antilog of an equation in R?

Comment: `10^-1.1050` returns `0.07852356`.

Comment: Rui Barradas and d.b : Thanks for the help! When I did:

round(10^(fit$coefficients), 2) 

it gave me a different B1 value, which doesn't fit the model

Comment: Maybe `10^coef(fit)` and if this does the job, `round`.

Comment: Rui Barradas: Tried that and it does change the B1 value. 10^coef(africamod1)
        (Intercept) log10(Prey_Biomass) 
          0.0785245           5.5585921 
The Bo value is perfect but I also need the B1 value to be 0.7450 or estimated close to it.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a math problem more than a computational problem. If you fit a log-log regression as follows:

```
fit <- lm(log10(Predator_Biomass)~log10(Prey_Biomass))
```

The underlying equation is

```
log10(y) = a+b*log10(x)
```

Raising 10 to both sides gives:

```
y = 10^(a+b*log10(x)) = 10^a * 10^(b*log10(x)) = 10^a * (10^log10(x))^b 
  = 10^a * x^b
```

The parameters `a` and `b` are the first and second coefficients of the linear model.  If you want to recover the parameters of `y = c*x^b` you need to antilog the intercept (`10^(coef(fit)[1])`), but the exponent `b` should be fine without transformation (`coef(fit)[2]`).

Comment: Thanks so much for this! This all make sense and definitely works to output the correct Bo but according to my TA I still need to be able to do the antilog of the equation so that I can get a summary that has the SE(Bo) which can then be used to determine the CI's. 

The SE(Bo) I have currently is for the: lm(log10(Predator_Biomass)~log10(Prey_Biomass))
which would not be correct to use because the Bo is -1.1050 in it.

Comment: you should probably ask your TA for clarification/clarify your question.  Do you want the confidence intervals of the *predicted values*?